# Permissions of a Shared Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, fuel-sdk, dataextensions

Is there a way I can obtain all the permissions of a shared data extension using API?

Comment: Any suggestions experts?

Comment: Took a quick look through the docs and the WSDL, and I'm not seeing any reference to it.  Cant confirm 100%, but it appears that is not exposed through the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer here would be no. I ran a describe API call against the "DataExtension" object type. I don't see anything related to permissions. Below are my results:

**Name | DataType | IsRetrievable | IsUpdatable**

```
ObjectID | String | true | true
PartnerKey | String | true | true
CustomerKey | String | true | true
Name | String | true | true
CreatedDate | DateTime | true | true
ModifiedDate | DateTime | true | true
Client.ID | Int32 | true | true
Description | String | true | true
IsSendable | Boolean | true | true
IsTestable | Boolean | true | true
SendableDataExtensionField.Name | String | true | true
SendableSubscriberField.Name | String | true | true
Template.CustomerKey | String | true | true
CategoryID | Int64 | true | true
Status | String | true | true
IsPlatformObject | Boolean | true | true
DataRetentionPeriodLength | Int32 | true | true
DataRetentionPeriodUnitOfMeasure | Int32 | true | true
RowBasedRetention | Boolean | true | true
ResetRetentionPeriodOnImport | Boolean | true | true
DeleteAtEndOfRetentionPeriod | Boolean | true | true
RetainUntil | String | true | true
DataRetentionPeriod | DateTimeUnitOfMeasure | true | true
SendableDataExtensionField | DataExtensionField | false | true
SendableSubscriberField | Attribute | false | true
Template | DataExtensionTemplate | false | true
Fields | DataExtensionField[] | false | true
Client | ClientID | false | true
PartnerProperties | APIProperty[] | false | true
ID | Int32 | false | true
Owner | Owner | false | true
CorrelationID | String | false | true
ObjectState | String | false | true
```